# Browsing Source Code on an iPhone

Tags: c++, iphone, c

I'm the kind of dork who enjoys reading source code in his spare time. I'm also the kind of dork who has an iPhone. What is the best way to read and browse code on such a device?

My initial thought is to use something like [LXR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxr) to generate hyperlinked pages, and upload them to my personal server, but I am interested in better/easier ways.

I am primarily reading C and C++ code, but support for other languages would be great.

I have no desire to jailbreak my iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Air Sharing](http://www.avatron.com/products/airsharing/) lets you copy over files via WebDav for viewing on your phone.  It even syntax colors source code.  According to the site, the supperted languages are, "C/C++, Objective C/C++, C#, Java, Javascript, XML, shell scripts, Perl, Ruby, Python, and more".

Comment: I have Air Sharing; I'll need to give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

[vim](http://www.iphonefaq.org/node/212) with ctags. Just a thought

Comment: holy crap, Apache on an iPhone!

Comment: Yes. I was looking at vim and completely looked over the small matter of "Apache". Holy Crap, indeed.